# Efficient way for writing -1 <= X[i,j] <=1

Tags: list-manipulation

I have an $m \times n$ variable $X$. I want to write the following constraint

```
cons = {-1 <= X[[1, 1]] <= 1, -1 <= X[[1, 2]] <= 1,..., -1 <= X[[m, n]] <=1}
```

How do I do it without writing out a constraint for every entry of $X$?

Comment: `-1 <= Flatten[X] <= 1 // Thread`.

Comment: Or `Map[(-1<=#<=1)&,Flatten[X]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are probably many ways to do this but here's one:

```
X = Array[x, {2, 2}];
cons ={Reduce[-1 <= X <= 1]}

(*{-1 <= x[1, 1] <= 1 && -1 <= x[1, 2] <= 1 && -1 <= x[2, 1] <= 1 && 
 -1 <= x[2, 2] <= 1}*)
```

Edit: Depending on the specific application, it may make more sense to use
`\[VectorLessEqual]`:

```
-1 \[VectorLessEqual] X \[VectorLessEqual] 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on @ydd 's answer, this is shorter and clearer.

```
VectorLessEqual[{-1,X,1}]
```